# Select a range, avoiding hidden cells, using ActiveCell.Offset()

Tags: vba, excel, filter

I am running a macro, that asks for a sheet name and a reference cell, and then selects a range of cells, surrounding the cell of our choice.
After applying a filter to my data, some of the rows become hidden, as they are not needed.
The problem is, that the macro does not take that into consideration and counts the hidden rows too.
Here is the code, that I use in the original version of the macro:

.....after applying some InputBox and a search for the user's value, the following row is executed:

```
Range(ActiveCell.Offset(90, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(-252, 2)).Select
Selection.Copy
```

In this way hidden rows are included in the selection.
I tried the following modification

```
Range(ActiveCell.Offset(90, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(-252, 2)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Selection.Copy
```

However without success.

I was wondering, can anyone suggest a way to use `ActiveCell.Offset` in combination with `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` resulting in the above described functionality of the macro -namely to select a range of cells avoiding the hidden rows after filtering?

Answer (score 4):

<s>To select just the visible cells from a range of selected cells, you can use the following line of code:</s>

```
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
```

Like in this Example:

```
Range(ActiveCell.Offset(90, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(-252, 2)).Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Selection.Copy
```

The Code Below is a example on how you could count the Rows.
So but there is a Problem where you have to think about.

If You Paste the Selection to your Original Sheet, there is a Chance that there are Hidden Rows in the area where you Copied the Selection.
If this is so, The Text which you copied there will be Hidden too.

So you have to Copied the Data to a new Sheet to avoid that Problem or you have to Copied the Data at the bottom of the Sheet 1.

```
Option Explicit
'Define a Constant for the Amount of Rows you Need
Private Const ConstAmountRows As Integer = 40
Sub Test()
    Dim intCountedRows As Integer
    Dim idx As Integer
    Dim intDifference As Integer

    idx = 0
    Do
        If Not (intCountedRows = ConstAmountRows) Then
            intCountedRows = ConstAmountRows
            idx = idx + 1
        End If
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        'Select the Range with the Amount of Rows you need ideally
        Range("A1:A" & intCountedRows + idx).Select

        'Select only the Visible Cells
        Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
        Selection.Copy

        Sheets("Sheet2").Select 'Select another Sheet
        '***-> Her you can select the Place you want to Paste the Text<-***
        Range("B1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste

        '*** Count the Rows that you Paste
        intCountedRows = Selection.Rows.Count
    'if the Counted Rows are not equal to the Amount. Repeat
    Loop While Not (intCountedRows >= ConstAmountRows)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice Moosli. 
I just used the syntax, suggested by you. However after running the updated macro, I can see that the area selected in the spreadsheet, is A2336:C2678, while there are hidden rows among those between row2336 and row2678. Hence when I paste the selection, I only get 331 rows ( which is less than the 343 I aimed for:) ).
Does anyone have a suggestion on how to make the macro "compensate" for the hidden rows and select some above row 2336 or below 2678, depending on whether the hidden rows are above or below the reference cell?